# DateTime issue with PHP - Storing Specific Date

Tags: php

I'd like to be able to store the following data inside a variable: 'Current Year-Current Month-10' (so i.e. **2013-9-10**)

Currently, I'm using: `echo date("Y-m-d");`

But this (as expected) displays the current Day, not 10 as I need it to.

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: `echo date("Y-m-10");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
echo date("Y-m-10");
```

If you want next month:

```
echo date('Y-m-10', strtotime('next month'));
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked. Final Question. Using this: `$fdate = date("Y-m-10");` how do I then add a month to this? So if I wanted to make the end result 2013-10-10 instead of 2013-9-10.

Comment: Brilliant - many thanks!!! And my final question - I promise. I am trying to do: `echo date('l, F j, Y h:i:s A', $fdate);` to show the date in a certain format, but now the result is `Thursday, January 1, 1970 01:33:33 AM` - any ideas why?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk What is `$fdate`?

Comment: Apologies. $fdate is just my variable name for storing the date. `$fdate = date("Y-m-10");`. I just want to re-format it from `Y-m-d` to `l, F j, Y h:i:s A`.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk The second parameter should be a unix timestamp.

Comment: Silly me :-) `echo date('l, F j, Y h:i:s A', strtotime($fdate));` now works. Thanks so much for your help & patience here.

Answer (score 4):

if you mean you want to hard code 10, then you could do:

```
$date = date("Y-m")."-10";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$var = date("Y-m-10");`